How to get linkedin profile URN
I’m working on a tool and need to extract the LinkedIn Profile URN of users. Specifically, I want to retrieve the URN in the format:
urn:li:fsd_profile:xxxx-xxxx

What I've Tried:

I’ve successfully retrieved the urn:li:person: followed by the user’s ID (e.g., urn:li:person:12345). However, this is not the format I need.
I’ve explored the LinkedIn API documentation and inspected the network requests made on LinkedIn's frontend, but I haven’t found a clear way to obtain the URN in the fsd_profile format.
What I'm Looking For:

Note:
I'm not looking for urn:li:person:sub. The goal is to obtain the urn:li:fsd_profile directly.
Thanks in advance!

Did you made any progres?

Can confirm that there's no API endpoint that will give you this.
I'm exploring an alternative approach using Selenium to drive a headless browser. On each profile page, there's a JSON data block that contains the data you're looking for in identityDashProfilesByMemberIdentity
